# Type "object {System.Collections.Generic.List<T>}" VS "System.Collections.Generic.List<T>"

Tags: c#, reflection

I am using reflection to get a List and trying to pass it into a delegate that receives a List.

However, when I use reflection the type of my list is:

```
object {System.Collections.Generic.List<T>}
```

And when I pass it to the delegate (of generics) I get an exception because it is expecting the type:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<T>
```

Just to confirm that this really the problem, I made a direct cast to `List<RealTClass>` and it worked. But, in my code I do not want to make this unnecessary cast... and also because I am using generics.

**Question #1**: Why the reflection returns the object as type: `object { X }` ?

**Question #2**: How can I "remove" the `object { X }` part from the type? Basically, I need a solution for this problem....

Thanks.

**UPDATE #1:** some code...

```
//METHOD receives 'obj' and 'includes'
T obj
Expression<Func<T, object[]>> includes = null
...
if (res && includes != null)
{
    var array = includes.Body as NewArrayExpression;
    if (array != null)
    {
        var exps = ((IEnumerable<object>)array.Expressions).ToArray();          
        for (var i = 0; i < exps.Length; i++)
        {
            var tartetListProperty = (exps[i] as MemberExpression).Member as PropertyInfo;
            var navigationPropertyForList = tartetListProperty.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(NavigationPropertyForList)) as NavigationPropertyForList[];
            if (navigationPropertyForList == null || navigationPropertyForList.Length == 0) continue;
            var navigationPropertyForListString = navigationPropertyForList[0].TargetPropertyName;
            if (tartetListProperty == null) continue;
            var list = tartetListProperty.GetValue(obj);    // WHERE I USE REFLECTION TO GET THE LIST
            var listOfType = list.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];

            var repDNI = uow.GetRepositoryDeleteNotIncludedAsyncByType(listOfType);
            await repDNI(list, navigationPropertyForListString, obj.Id); // THIS IS WHERE IT FAILS

            if (!res) break;
        }
    }
}
```

The `repDNI` object is correct and working if I do the correct casting, the only problem I am having is on getting the `list`, the type `object { X }` is surrounding my correct type.

Comment: [Boxing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx).

Comment: Do you get an exception or a compilation error? Could you add the code you're using?

Comment: @Lee Exception on runtime

Comment: How are you "using reflection to get a list"? Add your code.

Comment: @Sinatr That's what it looks like. However, why would a *reference type* be boxed?

Comment: as requested, I shared the code.

Comment: `GetValue()` returns `object`. If you cast the return value to the underlying type, then it would display correctly.

Comment: Are you sure this causes an error in runtime? It looks like you're passing `object` instead of `List<...>` to repDNI. Are you using `dynamic` somewhere? Note that the `object { ... }` notation is just the debugger visualization of the value, not the actual type - the actual type is still the `List<...>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work by changing the following line:

Before: `var list = tartetListProperty.GetValue(obj);`

After: `dynamic list = tartetListProperty.GetValue(obj);`

Answer (score -1):

You could cast to a generic list:

```
await repDNI((List<T>)list, navigationPropertyForListString, obj.Id);
```

As far as I know this should resolve your problem while remaining the generic functionality.

Comment: I wrote on my question that for confirmation I did what you just wrote now, but that is not an answer, since the TK of the list (and it can be more than one list, since I loop on the variable includes) is not a known type.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. You made a cast to the original Type, I made a cast to T. That will resolve your problem while remaining the flexibility of Generic Types.

Comment: I appreciate that you are trying to help, buy you are not reading my source code: I am working with a list based on the variable "includes", I loop on them and dynamically I am getting the corresponding list, the type T is not known and is DIFFERENTLY per "includes" element. And as you can see from the code, I am using expression trees / reflections / etc.... to processing this information..... the only known type "T" is applied on the variable "obj".

Comment: Explanation of what I am doing with my code: i receive the object "obj" of type T, and a list of unknown references to properties (lists) of the "obj". Then I loop on them, and for each element on each list I am calling a service on the target repository to delete this child element. I hope you understand what I am doing here.

Comment: Example: object is a "Blog Post" and has the properties List<Tags> and List<Comments>..... now I can call a method and pass the object "blogPost" and pass a list of the properties that I want to work with. I might want to delete all tags, or all tags AND comments, or just comments, or any other property list that "blogPost" has....